# Can FileSystemWatcher work OFFLINE?

Tags: c#, wpf, filesystemwatcher

I have written an application that needs to monitor changes to a
synchronized offline folder while the user is *not* connected to the network.
I have used the FileSystemWatcher and it works beautifully while the user is
connected to the network, however as soon as they are in an offline state
the FileSystemWatcher ceases to receive any events.

I can't find any documentation regarding file system events in offline
folders, does anyone have any experience in this space?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is. The [Native API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc296092(v=vs.85).aspx) looks pretty sparse, and any .NET control would need a native API to call through. And, of course, you're not *actually* changing the files in their original location when using them offline - there may be synchronization conflicts.

Comment: @Damien Thanks , Do you have an idea about "sync framework".. do u suggest to user this for offline support..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve overall, so I'm not sure what guidance you're after. If this was part of a larger problem that you're trying to solve, then we may do better if you ask a question about the overall problem, and how you current (broken) solution fits into it.

Comment: Set a watch on the local folder that stores the copy instead.  Ask at superuser.com if you don't know where that local folder is located.

Comment: @Damien: Thanks Again , I am trying to achieve Dropbox functionality and as of now use `FileSystemWatcher` in C#. Its working fine and all notification. Question is  FileSystemWatcher doesn't work if network is not available(offline).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks. I know where my local folder is but doesn't notify me changes in offline mode as DropBox does.

Comment: You should be able to do this with Sync Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623.aspx using the DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15656/Advanced-FileSystemWatcher

- two new public events: NetworkPathAvailable and NetworkPathUnavailable. In code, the user will look in these events to determine if the network path is available, and the code can take the appropriate measures to continue working, or die gracefully.*

Answer (score 0):

When the user goes offline, a Win32Error is caught in the FileSystemWatcher with an error message stating that "The specified network name is no longer available".  This can be detected in the **FileSystemWatcher.Error** event.

This exception also has the effect of changing the property **EnableRaisingEvents** to *false*.  Once the user is back online, set this to *true* again, and you will receive notifications once more.  Unfortunately, you will not be notified as to what happened while the user was offline.

So the ultimate answer to your question is no, the FileSystemWatcher does not deal with offline file notification.